# In Views, when using a filter on a datetime field, what is the time zone of the offset?

Tags: views, datetime

When I use an offset like "-4 hours" in a Views filter on a datetime field, which timezone is used?

**More details**

In Views, when I add a filter for a **datetime** field, I get the following options for **Value type**:

- A date in any machine readable format. CCYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS is preferred.
- An offset from the current time such as "+1 day" or "-2 hours -30 minutes"

On my site, users can set their own timezones. (/admin/config/regional/settings *Users may set their own time zone*)

So there are potentially three timezones in play:

- In the database, the strings for **datetime** are stored in the UTC timezone
- The site timezone is set to Tokyo
- The user timezone is set to Berlin

So, which of these timezones does the offset use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For datetime fields, it uses the timezone for the user viewing the page. If no user timezone is set, it uses the default site timezone.

See the relevant comment from *Drupal\datetime\Plugin\views\filter\Date.php*:

> Date-only fields do not have a time zone associated with them, so the filter input needs to use UTC for reference. Otherwise, use the time zone for the current user.

```
/**
 * Get the proper time zone to use in computations.
 *
 * Date-only fields do not have a time zone associated with them, so the
 * filter input needs to use UTC for reference. Otherwise, use the time zone
 * for the current user.
 *
 * @return string
 *   The time zone name.
 */
protected function getTimezone() {
  return $this->dateFormat === DateTimeItemInterface::DATE_STORAGE_FORMAT
    ? DateTimeItemInterface::STORAGE_TIMEZONE
    : date_default_timezone_get();
}
```